# Implicit setter resets other values

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, implicit

I have a class which contains two double variables. And added implicit operators.

```
public class MyClass
{
     public double A { get; set; }
     public double B { get; set; }

     static public implicit operator MyClass(double value)
     {
         return new MyClass{ A = value };
     }

     static public implicit operator double(MyClass classObject)
     {
         return classObject.A;
     }
}
```

What I want is that when I assign a double value, it sets A of MyClass object. And when I get a double value it returns A of MyClass object.

```
1. var taget = new MyClass { A = 1.0, B = 2.0 };
2. target = 3.0;
3. double ValA = target;
4. double ValB = target.B;
```

In this code example I created an object, assigned A and B. Now in line 2, I want that target.A sets to 3, but B value still remain 2. But line number 2 resets B value. So after the code executes ValA has 3.0 (as expected) but ValB has 0.0.

What should I do to maintain old values?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing your target variable here:

```
target = 3.0;
```

Because your cast operator returns a new object:

```
return new MyClass{ A = value };
```

You don't change your original target object, you are assigning a totally new object here in the target variable. You can't do what you want this way.

You want to convert a number to a MyClass object, but also "keep" the values of another MyClass object which is not used at all in this conversion.

Comment: I know that it is creating new object and hence other values are lost. Well the question is how I can do that?

Comment: The answer is you can't. Assignment operator cannot be overriden. Is this something you only need for ease of writing the code ? Or do you have another problem that you want to fix it this way ? If you have another problem then this is not a potential solution and you should look for another solution.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez I was just facing the same Problem. Since the only Thing you *can* do is implementing an implicit value conversion, which doesn't provide you the target-Object, this is impossible.